# NSArrayM objectAtIndex: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios5

i have search at this websit :

https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=nsarraym%20objectatindex%20index%205%20beyond%20bounds%20for%20empty%20array%27 but the solve no suit me.

i used pull refresh:  https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh at my app,but when i pull height too big,it give me crash :NSArrayM objectAtIndex: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array,if my tableview cell only visit 4 cells,it give me :NSArrayM objectAtIndex: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array,if only 3 cells can visit it give me NSArrayM objectAtIndex: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array. at  the same i used other pull refresh lib like:https://github.com/emreberge/EGOTableViewPullRefresh  as so on,give me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is beyond bounds: your array is empty, you can not extract any object form it.

If the array has `n` objects, you can retrieve up to index `n - 1`. An empty array has 0 objects, so you can not even retrieve index 0.

Comment: Well, then the second line of code ("data = [NSData...") is causing the crash; but I don't see any array. Perhaps `urlAddress` is already deallocated and the array error comes from inside `URLWithString:`?

Comment: Try `NSLog("Address String: %@", urlAddress);` instead of `data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] options:0 error:&error1];`

Comment: when i pull height < cell height all is ok,but when > cell height,my code is wrong

Comment: The NSURL created from the string is valid too? Try `NSURL* url = [NSURL URLURLWithString: urlAddress]; data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:0 error:&error1];` and see if url is always not-nil

Comment: NSLog(@"Address URL: %@", [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress]); not  nil

Comment: 2012-07-05 19:32:27.411 MyAura[12779:3e0b] Address String: http://services.portaura.mobi/AuraMesh/auraFinder/findPeoples?ll=31.2,121.6&source=tencent,netease,kaixin&myAuraId=4ff570c2e4b0f2501c12b88e
2012-07-05 19:32:27.414 MyAura[12779:3e0b] Address URL: http://services.portaura.mobi/AuraMesh/auraFinder/findPeoples?ll=31.2,121.6&source=tencent,netease,kaixin&myAuraId=4ff570c2e4b0f2501c12b88e
2012-07-05 19:32:27.658 MyAura[12779:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown there?

Comment: but you know 333 is print,222is not print,i  think the mistake is at here

Comment: NSLog(@"****333");
    NSLog(@"Address String: %@", urlAddress);
    NSLog(@"Address URL: %@", [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress]);
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress]  options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error1];
     NSLog(@"****222");
only the 222not print